# Проблема с массивом в с++

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Задание: на плоскости задана прямая и множество точек. Найти точки находящиеся на минимальном и максимальном расстоянии от прямой.
 Код проги:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
int Xn,Yn,Xk,Yk;
float d,N;
int x[i];
int y[i];
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout<<"Введите количество точек N - ";
    cin>>N;
      if (N<=0) {
       cout<<"Ошибка, количиство точек, это положительное число"<<endl<<"Введите количество точек - ";
cin>>N;
              }
    cout<<"Введите координаты прямой через пробел Xn, Yn, Xk, Yk"; cin>>Xn>>Yn>>Xk>>Yk;
         for (i=1; i<N; i++)
          cout<<"Введите координаты точек"; cin>>x[i];
                                            cin>>y[i];
         for (i=1; i<N; i++)
         d[i]=((Yn-Yk)*x[i]+(Xk-Xn)*y[i]+((Xn*Yk)-(Xk*Yn)))/sqrt((pow(Xk-Xn),2)+(pow(Yk-Yn),2))
    min=d[1];
    max=d[1];
         for (i=2; i<N; i++) {
                if (d[i]<min)
                min=d[i];
                else {
                    if d[i]>max
                    max=d[i];
                }
         }
  cout<<"Точка максимальна - "; cin>>max;
  cout<<"Точка минимальна - "; cin>>min;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Извините, от этого кода у меня глаза завяли.*

Более разумное решение - оформить вспомогательную структуру `Point` и использовать стандартный алгоритм для нахождения минимального элемента с собственным `Comparator'ом`.

*В коде это может выглядеть следующим образом:*

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Point
{
    Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) { }

    // Теоретически, может быть любой тип, который поддерживает
    // запись в кортеж (-,-), например, 'float'.
    int x, y;
};

struct PlaneDistancePointComparator
{
    bool operator()(const Point& point1, const Point& point2)
    {
        // Необходимо сравнить точки в плане расстояния до
        // соответствующей плоскости.
        return Distance(point1, plane) < Distance(point2, plane);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<Point> points;

    // Прочитать исходные точки и занести их в 'std::vector' с помощью
    // std::vector::push_back(Point(-,-));

    const Point& minimalElement = *std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end(), PlaneDistancePointComparator());

    const Point& maximalElement = *std::max_element(points.begin(), points.end(), PlaneDistancePointComparator());

    // Получили 2 ссылки на структуры точек с минимальным и максимальным
    // расстоянием до плоскости.
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый Котик, всем известно, что Вы большой знаток STL, boost и пр. Но человек, видимо, только недавно начал учить С++, ему бы попроще как-то надо...

Comment: @mikillskegg Пожалуй, соглашусь. Сейчас попробуем)

Answer (score 1):

Нормальный код, свою задачу он выполняет. Только массивы объявите по человечески. Число точек N наверное все таки целое, координаты точек наоборот вещественные. Массивы, раз они заранее неизвестного размера, выделяйте через new, дистанции тоже массив, в функции pow лишняя скобка... и прочая и прочая